# Custom Feature Engineering in SageMaker Model

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am using Batch Transform in SageMaker to call a stored XGBoost model and score it on a data stored in S3. However, before I call the model I have to do several transformations on the columns.

The following is the code used for Batch Transformation:

```
batch_input = 's3://{}/{}/batch/test_data_Batch.csv'.format(bucket,prefix) # test data used for prediction
batch_output = 's3://{}/{}/batch/batch-inference/test_data_Batch.csv.out'.format(bucket,prefix)
Modelname = '<your_model_name_here>' # the model name we already have
transformJobName = 'DEMO-xgboost-churn-call-batch'+ strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())

client = boto3.client('sagemaker')

create_batch = client.create_transform_job(
    TransformJobName=transformJobName,
    ModelName=Modelname,
    MaxConcurrentTransforms=0,
    MaxPayloadInMB=6,
    BatchStrategy='MultiRecord',
    TransformInput={
        'DataSource': {
            'S3DataSource': {
                'S3DataType': 'S3Prefix',
                'S3Uri': batch_input 
            }
        },
        'ContentType': 'text/csv',
        'CompressionType': 'None',
        'SplitType': 'Line'
    },
    TransformOutput={
        'S3OutputPath': batch_output,
        'AssembleWith': 'Line'
    },
    TransformResources={
        'InstanceType': 'ml.m4.xlarge',
        'InstanceCount': 1
    }
    )
```

How can I call a feature engineering Python function to transform the data before I run the Batch Transform using XGBoost model? Some pointers would help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the late response.

I believe there are a few approaches you can take to do some preprocessing in SageMaker in conjunction with Batch.

I am assuming that you are using the XGBoost Image that SageMaker provides in: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-xgboost-container.

1. If you are using the open sourced SageMaker XGBoost container, then you can modify your Model Image script to handle your preprocessing and postprocessing. This will require you to extend or build the XGBoost Image and host it as an ECR image in your AWS account.

For an example on extending a framework image see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/prebuilt-containers-extend.html

After extending the image, you would want to modify your user script to handle your preprocessing.

Example of a userscript in the XGBoost container: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-xgboost-container/blob/master/test/resources/boston/single_machine_customer_script.py

This could take some time and I would recommend using the Python SDK and local mode for faster iterations: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-local-mode.

2. Utilize SageMaker Inference pipelines to have a separate Image to handle preprocessing your data before using SageMaker batch.

Similar to approach above, however in this case we would generate a separate Image to handle solely preprocessing our data and then passing that data to our original model.

Depending on your approach this can require extending an existing container or creating a new one entirely with your required dependencies.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/inference-pipeline-batch.html

3. There is also SageMaker Processing

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-sagemaker-processing-fully-managed-data-processing-and-model-evaluation/